# when i call self.view.removeFromSuperview() on uipageviewcontroller then black screen shows up

Tags: ios, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I have page view controller and want to remove it and go back to homeviewcontroller, but when i call

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

it show black screen instead of remove it and go back to parent

Comment: show the code that presents the pageViewController

Comment: I got the solution dear in answer below thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use removeFromSuperView() on view controller views. Instead use `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` if you presented it modally, or use `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` if you pushed it.

Comment: sure .. it is saying to wait 5 minutes